# where do I get a client_id from?

Tags: facebook, registration

I am new to Facebook based development and just require a basic Facebook registration form, I've found the "registration form and its html to embed into my website", but need a client_id so I can use it. Where do I get this from?

Comment: You need to register for an facebook app in order to it all working.

Comment: please mark Tom's answer as correct.

Comment: @comiventor I'm not sure bumping five year old threads from anonymous users is productive.

Answer (score 29):

http://developers.facebook.com/apps

After creating an app, the App ID / Client ID is shown.

Answer (score 9):

**Finding Facebook App ID, App Secret and Client Token:**

You can find your App ID and App Secret in Settings/basic:

[image: App ID and App Secret]

The Client Token can be found at Settings/advanced:

[image: Client Token]

> https://developers.facebook.com/apps/Your_App_ID/settings/

Comment: Just to be clear. Is Client token = client id?